# Swing Worker not processing update

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

Was trying to get a zip file manager to update a JTextArea but for some reason the process() never gets executed.

**EDIT**

Here is the entire program as suggested:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Reader extends JFrame{

    // Sets the Window bar Title and the size of the window
    private static String windowTitle = "SRT Converter";
    private static Dimension windowSize = new Dimension(400,400);
    private JTextField txtFileIn;

    private File fileIn = null;
    private File fileOut = null;
    private JTextArea txtOutputPanel;

    public Reader() {

        JButton btnSelectArchive = new JButton("Select Archive");
        btnSelectArchive.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String path = fileOpenDialog();
                if(!path.isEmpty()){
                    fileIn = new File(path);
                    String[] tokens = path.split("\\\\");
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    for(int i = 0; i < tokens.length -1; i++)
                    {
                        sb.append(tokens[i] + "\\");
                    }
                    sb.append("Transcript.txt");
                    fileOut = new File(sb.toString());
                    txtFileIn.setText(fileIn.toString());
                }
                else {
                    String message = "You need to select an archive file (zip)";
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message,"No File", JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
                }
            }
        });
        getContentPane().setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[101px,grow][71px,grow][86px,grow]", "[23px][][][][][][grow]"));
        getContentPane().add(btnSelectArchive, "cell 0 0,growx,aligny top");

        txtFileIn = new JTextField();
        getContentPane().add(txtFileIn, "cell 1 0 2 1,growx,aligny center");
        txtFileIn.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnConvert = new JButton("Convert");
        btnConvert.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                readZipFile();
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(btnConvert, "cell 0 1,growx,aligny top");

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        getContentPane().add(scrollPane, "cell 0 2 3 5,grow");

        txtOutputPanel = new JTextArea();
        scrollPane.setViewportView(txtOutputPanel);
    }

    // Read in a zip file
    private void readZipFile(){

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ZipFile zipFile = null;
                try {
                    zipFile = new ZipFile(fileIn);
                    Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries();
                    while(entries.hasMoreElements()){
                        final ZipEntry entry = entries.nextElement();

                        writeFile("\n\n");
                        writeFile(entry.getName());
                        writeFile("\n");

                        FileWriterWorker fr = new FileWriterWorker(zipFile, entry);
                        fr.execute();

                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        t.start();

    }

    /** 
     * Allows user to pick a file from a directory (base directory set when created)
     * 
     * @param fileChooser -- JFileChooser to Use
     * @param panel -- panel to tie dialogBox to
     * @return -- string with the path name
     */
    private String fileOpenDialog()
    {
        String path = null;
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser(".");
        fileChooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
        //      fileChooser.setFileFilter(filter);

        int openFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(getContentPane());

        if (openFile == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            // check if file has extension
            if (file.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".zip"))
            {
                path = file.getAbsolutePath();  // if it does just return it
            } else {
                path = file.getAbsolutePath() + ".zip";  // if it does not append it to the path
            }
        } else {
            path = "";      // set path to null if no file was selected (avoids null exception)
        }
        return path;        // return path to file
    }


    private void writeFile(String str){

        BufferedWriter bw = null;

        if(fileOut == null){
            try {
                throw new Exception("Output File Does not exist");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        try {
            bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileOut + "Transcript.txt", true));
            bw.write(str);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.flush();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } finally {                       // always close the file
            if (bw != null) try {
                bw.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe2) {/* just ignore it */}
        }


    }


    /**
     *  Main program driver
     * 
     * @param args - Takes no arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    InitalizeAndShowGUI();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    private static void InitalizeAndShowGUI(){

        // Create the main window
        Reader mWindow = new Reader();
        mWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mWindow.setTitle(windowTitle);
        mWindow.setMinimumSize(windowSize); // smallest window can get

        // Set window in center of Default Monitor Window
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice device = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
        Rectangle screenRect = device.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds();
        mWindow.setLocation(screenRect.width/2 - windowSize.width/2,
                screenRect.height/2 - windowSize.height/2);

        mWindow.pack();
        mWindow.setVisible(true);
    }

    private class FileWriterWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, String>{
        private ZipFile zipFile;
        private ZipEntry entry;

        public FileWriterWorker(ZipFile zipFile, ZipEntry entry){
            this.zipFile = zipFile;
            this.entry = entry;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {

            InputStream stream = zipFile.getInputStream(entry);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if(line.contains("0:") || line.isEmpty())
                    continue;

                writeFile(line);

            }
            writeFile("\n\n");
            publish(entry.getName());
            System.out.println(entry.getName());
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<String> update) {
            for (String str : update) {
                txtOutputPanel.append(str + "\n");  
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Everything works correctly and the output file is created and the file contents of the zip are written successfully. The SwingWorker is being implemented to update the user as to the current place in the zip file that is being read since the zip contains a lot of files and will take some time to read and write out. I tried placing a system out just after publish() call and that gets executed but the System.out.println(str) in process() never fires. Everything works except the process() method Even put a sysout directly before the loop in process() and that never gets executed. Any idea?? puzzled...

**EDIT2**

I posted the entire example and the final solution was to place the call to readZipFile() method to read file in its own thread while continuing to update the writer in the SwingWorker which updates the EDT thread that the GUI runs in. Thanks all!

Comment: Try putting a `Thread.yield` or `Thread.sleep(1)` within the `while-loop` in the `doInBackground` method...

Comment: No that didn't help. Like I said it does output to console if I put a sysout statement directly after the publish() command but will never execute the process() command. In the basic sense there's not much to this. I am using Java 8.

Comment: There is no direct relationship between `publish` and `process`, `process` will only be called if the `SwingWorker` can "find" the time to do it...so, if you inject a small delay into the processing, it should allow the `SwingWorker` time to setup the callback

Comment: Agreed. Every example I've seen works the same way. This one just doesn't. I'll keep researching.

Comment: When `doInBackground` ends, does `process` get called?

Comment: I suspect that you hanged the EDT thread (the thread where process is executed) in the when you built and called this worker. I'd suggest you show a full program where you use it.

Comment: `"Here is a semi working example (some trivial code left out to keep this short such as the full constructor):"` -- if you still need help, get rid of the "*semi*" working example and post a fully working short example, an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There will be no invocation of `process` as long as `readZipFile()`, which runs on the event dispatch thread, hasn’t returned. And that method processes the entire zip file. So there will be no invocation of `process` showing progress but upon entire completion, Swing should catch up processing the scheduled items.